# Multiple regression vs Simple regression difference in p-value

Tags: statistics, regression, linear-regression

Why are P-values different when I do

DV with independent variables A and B (multiple)
versus same DV with independent variable A only? (simple)

The p-value for Variable A in the multiple regression is higher than that of simple regression.

Comment: Why would you expect them to be the same?

Comment: I mean I expected them to be different but I need to understand what's responsible for the difference.

Comment: Roughly speaking, in the simple regression the coefficient for A is trying to explain the variability in the response variable. However, in multiple regression, the coefficient for A is trying to explain the variability in the response variable *while holding variable B fixed*. These are two different linear models, which lead to two different hypothesis tests. I think the only case where things would end up being the same is if A and B are orthogonal.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your response was a great help!